# how to start with blackberry development

Tags: java, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, blackberry

I want to start with BlackBerry development for smarthphones.

I see two ways...

1. Eclipse
2. Visual Studio

I have Windows 7 64 bits... with Visual Studio 2008. I install the Visual Studio Plugin, I create a BlackBerry Project, but when I try to Save the Project I can't, a message error appears.
Other problem are I cant compile to the simulator. I have the simulator for BlackBerry Curve 8520.

How I can develop with Eclipse... I see is other method... but How I can link the simulator with eclipse...

If Is eclipse... what language is needed ??... In Visual Studio are HTML + Javascript...
But... with eclipse ?? is HTML + Javascript too ??? or maybe are JAVA ?

I hope anybody can help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Please read this [post](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Useful-links-for-novice-and-experienced-programmers/m-p/116924) from http://supportforums.blackberry.com

Comment: Check out [this link](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Useful-links-for-novice-and-experienced-programmers/m-p/116924), it contains humongous collection of BB materials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**---- The link given by [adatapost](https://stackoverflow.com/users/142822/adatapost) is the single most important and rich collection of resources for the beginners.**

For a quick start you may like following links:

[Setting up your development tools for BlackBerry Java applications](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Setting-up-your-development-tools-for-BlackBerry-Java/ta-p/442687)

[Writing Your First Application](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/rim/attachments/rim/java_dev@tkb/9/1/Writing_Your_First_Application_V5.pdf)

You have to download Blackberry Plugins for Eclipse. And Java will be the programming language.

Comment: Ok friend, thanks... I go to check.
My first way are to do in Javascript + HTML. But I see is more beauty do this in JAVA, thanks again :)